# How to connect local SQL server database using Google JDBC

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, jdbc, google-apps-script

I have a question here. I want to set up a Google sheet and populate this sheet with numbers from my local database. And my network is VPN network. I program in Google spreadsheet script editor. Using the following code to connect my local database:

```
var address = '10.0.0.71:1433/DatabaseName';
var username = 'DOMAIN\username';
var password = 'root';
var dbUrl = 'jdbc:sqlserver://' + address; 


function createDatabase() {
  var conn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbUrl, username, password);
  var stmt = conn.createStatement();
  var rs = stmt.execute('SELECT * FROM ITEM');

  stmt.close();
  conn.close();
}
```

However, this connection test doesn't work at all.
The error is:
**Failed to establish a database connection. Check connection string, username and password.**

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding of Google Apps Scripts, your database need to be reachable from the Internet (that's how Google works, in the Cloud).

Comment: Well, I use local database. And my database is reachable. I thing google server cannot reach my database. But I don't know why.